# JSON data to REST API using cURL give a blank response

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I'm trying to post data to a JIRA REST API but I get a blank response back.  The code sits in two files.  Here's the code located on the jira.json file:

```
{
"fields": {
            "project":
                        {
                            "id": "19600"
                        },
            "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
                            "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
                            "issuetype": {
                                                "name": "Task"
                                         }
                }
}
```

and the php code:

```
<?php

$jsondata = file_get_contents("jira.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);

//print_r($json);




$url_send ="http://jira.greentea.co.za:8091/rest/api/2/issue/";
$str_data = json_encode($json);

//print_r($str_data);

function sendPostData($url, $post){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);  

  if($result)
    {
        return 1;
    }
  else{
        return 0;
       }
  }



$time =  sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);
var_dump($time);
?>
```

I get a zero `int(0)` meaning that the result variable returned a blank result.  This is the the cURL Command that I converted to php. data will be replaced by the json array:

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Comment: Have you noticed you've not included the Content-type header in your PHP code? You can also use `curl_getinfo()` to get the HTTP code, which might give you an idea as to what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you have CURL enabled with your PHP, try to use this snippet from my code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data)));
```

Let me know if this works for you.